# WITH Clause Enhancements in Oracle Database 12c

Tags: oracle, plsql, common-table-expression

I would like to know the performance issues(if any) of PROCEDURE and FUNCTION usage in new WITH Clause feature introduced in 12c release 1.

Comment: I think there is no general answer.
that depends on the procedure

Answer (score 1):

LMGTFY

http://db-oriented.com/2015/11/14/write-less-with-more-part-8/

It generally improves performance, since it doesn't require a context-switch (from the SQL engine to the PL/SQL engine).

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1#performance-advantages

> From this we can see the inline function definition takes approximately one third the elapsed time and CPU time to complete.

However, if you're just trying to improve performance...

https://logicalread.com/add-functions-oracle-12c-with-clause-mc08/#.XQuCxHVKhhE

> Much to the surprise of many Oracle Database 12c early adopters, adding the PRAGMA UDF clause to regular functions consistently outruns WITH clause functions (as shown in the previous example—0.06 instead of 0.07).

Comment: Small correction: there is still a context switch, but the cost of that switch is reduced.